# .net wrapper for Perforce API?

Tags: c#, .net, perforce

I'm currently developing an application in .NET 4 which has to interact with a Perforce server.

My team previously developed some sort of wrapper using the Perforce API, but its missing quite a few use-cases and doesn't properly handle exceptions. In short, it's not something that I can really use as-is, as it would require considerable effort to make it as "bullet-proof" as possible.

I was wondering if there's a Perforce API wrapper that exists for .NET which properly handles exceptions ?

As I was evaluating the usability of our in-house wrapper, I came up with a list of exceptions and use-cases our application would need to handle (and the wrapper would need to throw).

The list was quite exhaustive, which prompted me to wonder if some sort of wrapper already existed.

Comment: The first result from a quick google search of *perforce c# api*: http://public.perforce.com/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/p4com/main/index.html

Comment: I'm not looking for an API, I'm looking for a wrapper.

Comment: from the link that M.Babcock posted: "P4API.Net is entirely managed code and is fully supported by Perforce. This is now the recommended interface to use on Windows"

Comment: Unfortunately Mr. Babcock's initial response didn't point to that particular page, but instead to a Google page prior to being edited. Thanks for the remark, I'll take a look at that API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to check out the [P4API.NET](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/Perforce-Software-Version-Management/complete_list/Customer%20Downloads?qt-perforce_downloads_step_3=3#qt-perforce_downloads_step_3#48) library, which is provided by Perforce. Or you could use the [P4.NET](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4.net) library, which isn't an official release from Perforce, but has been around for a while.

I've used P4.NET several times, and been pretty happy with it. You can get the .NET 4 libraries [here](https://github.com/milang/P4.net), as I believe the original library only had support for .NET 2.

Comment: Much appreciated Mike, I'll take a look at both of them. Have you also used P4API.NET ? I was wondering how both compare.

Comment: I haven't used P4API.NET yet (it's on my todo list), but I did briefly go over the documentation. I remember thinking it looked somewhat comparable to P4.NET.

Answer (score 3):

There is also my (not that well tested) c# wrapper around the p4 exe. The main (only?) advantage of this over the others is that it builds and works under mono too. It does not depend on COM or the perforce C++ libraries.

https://github.com/inorton/p4-sharp

```
P4Shell p = new P4Shell();

if ( p.Login("inb","password") )
    Console.WriteLine("logged in");

Console.WriteLine( p.WorkspaceName );
Console.WriteLine( p.WorkspaceRoot );

var dirs = p.Dirs("//nCipher/dev/home/inb/*");

foreach ( var d in dirs )
    Console.WriteLine(" + {0}", d);
```

P.S. I wasn't trying to be funny by storing it in github :)