# p4 opened -a in C# Perforce Wrapper or P4 API

Tags: c#, api, wrapper, perforce

I found this thread very helpful and I would like to ask Ian Norton about his wrapper.  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146677/net-wrapper-for-perforce-api/13925232#13925232) is the link to the wrapper I was trying that IanNorton had posted. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask and I also don't want to create a new thread when it pertains to his response. So I will go ahead and suffer whatever backlash may come my way.

I am currently trying to use your wrapper and i cannot seem to seem to get it to trigger anything when I run it. I do not want to use options as i just want to set this as an .exe that runs on a timer. Quite simply, I would like to use the p4 opened -a cmd and print the out puts to a file. That is it. Any help would be greatly appreciated by this NooB.

Thank you very much!

This is as far as I got with just using the Command Line.  Unfortunately I could not output my info to a text file.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace P4OpenCMD
{
    class P4Opened
    {
        // Main begins program execution.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string temp = string.Empty;

            if (temp != string.Empty)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;

                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();

                StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;

                using (sw = p.StandardInput)
                {
                    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("set P4PORT=####");
                        sw.WriteLine("set P4USER=####");
                        sw.WriteLine("set P4CLIENT=####");
                        sw.WriteLine("set P4PASSWD=####");
                        sw.WriteLine("p4 opened -a //Depot/...");
                        sw.WriteLine("pause;");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                sw.Close();
                p.WaitForExit();
                p.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this, you should be in good shape:

```
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.Arguments = "/c p4 opened > opened.txt";
```

Comment: I had started to simply use the cmd line and was having success (except for the output to file) and it was recommended that I use the API.  Personally I would just like to get this done :)